# Evaluate the following limits. $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \tan x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Evaluate limits. Note assume that $\sin x, 1−\cos x, \tan x$, and $\sqrt[3]{x}$ converge to 0 as $x\to 0$. Note: Do *not* use L'Hospital's Rule.

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$
2. $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \tan x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$

For (1), observe that
$$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = \frac{(x-1)\sum_{i=1}^n x^{n-i}1^{i-1}}{x-1} =\sum_{i=1}^n x^{n-i}.$$
Then
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \sum_{i=1}^n x^{n-i} = \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n.$$

For (2), observe that
$$\left|\tan x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right| \leq \tan x; \forall x \neq 0.$$
Then by the squeeze theorem, we have that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \tan x\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 0$$

Are these find evaluations of the limits?

Comment: It's correct. (I wonder why you put the 'binomial-coefficients' tag though.)

Comment: @nejimban, I thought the property I was using for (1) was making use of expanding a binomial coefficient. I honestly can't remember what the name of the property is.

Comment: The identity you used in (1) follows from the geometric sum. I don't know if that has a proper name in English, but it's not binomial. Anyway, congrats for not using L'Hôpital's rule :)

Comment: @nejimban, I see, thank you :) I fixed the tags.